# Screen Joining between iPhone and iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I mean two iPhone devices should be connected with Bluetooth or WiFi and the UI of the one device should be extended to another iPhone device(not sharing the screen). Do we have the way to do this in iOS?

Comment: Wow, I am actually very interested in finding the answer to this one.

Answer (score 0):

Bump API is the best example and will be useful to you to connect two devices(IOS/Android) and transfer data between them.